# Storing continuous speech recognition from microphone on MS Azure to a separate variable

Tags: python, python-3.x, azure, speech-recognition, speech-to-text

I have the following Python code that can continuously recognize your voice. It works fine, I just need to store the final result (after certainly long speech is finished) to one variable...

```
import azure.cognitiveservices.speech as speechsdk
import os
import time


path = os.getcwd()
# Creates an instance of a speech config with specified subscription key and service region.
# Replace with your own subscription key and region identifier from here: 
https://aka.ms/speech/sdkregion
speech_key, service_region = "6.....9", "eastus"
speech_config = speechsdk.SpeechConfig(subscription=speech_key, region=service_region)

# Creates a recognizer with the given settings
speech_config.speech_recognition_language="en-US"
#source_language_config = speechsdk.languageconfig.SourceLanguageConfig("en-US", "The Endpoint ID for 
your custom model.")
speech_recognizer = speechsdk.SpeechRecognizer(speech_config=speech_config)

done = False 
def stop_cb(evt):
print('CLOSING on {}'.format(evt))
speech_recognizer.stop_continuous_recognition()
global done
done= True


#Connect callbacks to the events fired by the speech recognizer    
speech_recognizer.recognizing.connect(lambda evt: print('RECOGNIZING: {}'.format(evt)))
speech_recognizer.recognized.connect(lambda evt: print('RECOGNIZED: {}'.format(evt)))
speech_recognizer.session_started.connect(lambda evt: print('SESSION STARTED: {}'.format(evt)))
speech_recognizer.session_stopped.connect(lambda evt: print('SESSION STOPPED {}'.format(evt)))
speech_recognizer.canceled.connect(lambda evt: print('CANCELED {}'.format(evt)))
# stop continuous recognition on either session stopped or canceled events
speech_recognizer.session_stopped.connect(stop_cb)
speech_recognizer.canceled.connect(stop_cb)

speech_recognizer.start_continuous_recognition()

while not done:
    time.sleep(.5)
```

Is it possible to make a separate variable and store the final result in it? Can't figure out how...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
import azure.cognitiveservices.speech as speechsdk
import os
import time

path = os.getcwd()

speech_key, service_region = "", ""
speech_config = speechsdk.SpeechConfig(subscription=speech_key, region=service_region)

speech_config.speech_recognition_language="en-US"

speech_recognizer = speechsdk.SpeechRecognizer(speech_config=speech_config)

result = ''
done = False 

def stop_cb(evt):
    print('CLOSING on {}'.format(evt))
    speech_recognizer.stop_continuous_recognition()
    global done
    done= True




def collectResult(evt):
   global result 
   result += evt.result.text

speech_recognizer.recognized.connect(lambda evt: collectResult(evt))

speech_recognizer.session_started.connect(lambda evt: print('SESSION STARTED: {}'.format(evt)))
speech_recognizer.session_stopped.connect(lambda evt: print('SESSION STOPPED {}'.format(evt)))
speech_recognizer.canceled.connect(lambda evt: print('CANCELED {}'.format(evt)))

speech_recognizer.session_stopped.connect(stop_cb)
speech_recognizer.canceled.connect(stop_cb)

speech_recognizer.start_continuous_recognition()

while not done:
    print(result)
    time.sleep(.5)
```

Comment: That seems to work fine. Thanks! :D How do I access the variable now elsewhere in the code? For example, if I wanted to print it (variable with the whole text) separately after the process is done.

Comment: @scrap_tech_guy, I have updated my code, just  print `result` to get all results

Comment: Thank you so much! Appreciate your time. :D

Comment: @scrap_tech_guy, glad to know my post is helpful, pls click the checkmark beside my post so that it will close the question and it also will help others :)

Comment: Yes sirrr. Done!